# Regex to find a file with system time

Tags: regex

I have a folder where, i'll get files named as the date of that day.

Eg:

```
test.021314
test.021414
```

In the folder location i get a single file for each day. So, there will be number of files in it.

File name is constructed in following manner;

Constant prefix('test')+. date(mmddyy format)

I need to pick a file which should match with the current date. I have to use 'regex' to select the file..

Can anyone point me what would be the correct regex to pick the file which has the system date?

Comment: Use a less crazy date format, you will thank yourself many times over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but try

```
test\.\d{6}
```

### EXPLAINED

`test.` - match literally 'test.'

`\d{6}` - match 6 digits consecutively

Comment: so it will match; 'test.021314', 'test.021414'.. like all files?

Comment: yes, if you want to be specific then do `test.021414` but for the life of me i dont see any need for regex here

Comment: system provides a way to pick files useing regular expression..Now i have files with date..SO , i need to use regex..there is no any other option for me..

Comment: wow, a system that restricts to regex only, that's restrictive :)

Answer (score 1):

As you need to pick file based on current date, then you can make the file name using date function 
ex:

```
var d = new Date();
var filename = "test."+(d.getMonth()+1).toString()+d.getDate().toString()+d.getFullYear().toString()
```

Regular expression will not help in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
/test\.\d{2}(14)\d{2}/
```

this will match current day here i have given 14.

[demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3Li)

Comment: so, in this case each and every time , i need to edit that '14' value to 15, 16 so on..Isn't it? once deployed the implementation, i can not edit the code..can i pass a variable instead of '14' value..So, i can pass system current date as variable..

Comment: it is not poosible in regex

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is a static regex, it cannot be done. The regex facility itself has no way to know the current date. Perhaps you could use some external tool to update the regex every midnight?